# Append a nested dictionary to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to append a nested dictionary to a dictionary, I have searched the internet and couldn't find an answer.

I tried

```
Colors = {}

a = {"1:1":{255,1,2}}
b = {"2:1":{1,255,2}}
Colors.update(a)
Colors.update(b)

print(Colors)
```

It prints

```
{'1:1': {1, 2, 255}, '2:1': {1, 2, 255}}
```

Instead of

```
{'1:1': {255,1,2}, '2:1': {1,255,2}}
```

Comment: sets in python are unordered. You probably want to use ordered structure such as list or tuple, for example: `a = {"1:1":[255,1,2]}`

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between your "expected output" and your "actual output". The values of the dictionary are *sets* so the order of the elements is meaningless!

Comment: It does matter because the values represent rgb so if they get mixed,it would have different colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the values don't keep their order is because you're using sets and not lists. Unlike lists, sets are unordered ([you can read more here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)).
To fix your issue, you can use lists instead (note the `{}` turned into `[]`:

```py
Colors = {}

a = {"1:1":[255,1,2]}
b = {"2:1":[1,255,2]}
Colors.update(a)
Colors.update(b)

print(Colors)
```

Which prints:

```py
{'1:1': [255, 1, 2], '2:1': [1, 255, 2]}
```